# Aplicar css al seleccionar una opción

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría saber si es posible aplicar un `hover` de `css` cuando una opción de un `select` es escogida.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    img {
        width: 40%
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h1>PARTES DEL COCHE</h1>
    <form action="a.php">
        <select name="coche" id="coche">
            <option value="rueda">Rueda</option>
            <option value="parrilla">Parrilla</option>
            <option value="espejo">Espejo</option>
            <option value="puerta">Puerta</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <br>
    <img src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/AebbV/s1/audi-a3-sportback-45-tfsi-e-2021.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

Al seleccionar la opción rueda, quiero hacer un `point-zoom` sobre la rueda del coche de la imagen, y así con todas las opciones del desplegable.

Lo que he probado es lo siguiente. Al selecionar una opcion, que añada a la imagen un borde negro, pero no se aplica correctamente.

```
option:checked img {
        border: 10px solid black;
    }
```

Desconozco si esto es posible y como se haría.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta se puede responder con un simple **Si, es posible** partiendo de eso te recomiendo que añadas que has intentado, puedes hacerlo desde las clases de css con por ejemplo: `#coche.pieza:hover{//css }` y añadiendo al  option una clase.

Comment: Lo que no comprendo es como indicas que al seleccionar una de las opciones el `css` actué sobre la imagen inferior.

Comment: @NicolasOñate `pieza` es un identificador o una clase de las opciones del `select`? Y porque usar `hover` si no me interesa que se haga cuando paso el ratón por encima sino cuando selecciono una opción?

Comment: De hecho, si no me equivoco, no es posible hacerlo con CSS puro, por la manera en que los elementos están anidados. No existen selectores para llamar a la imagen a partir del hijo de otro padre, sin relación alguna con él. Con javascript vanilla sería muy fácil de hacer, simplemente asignando a ambos elementos una clase que los relacione.

Comment: @Bettylex gracias por tu aportación, pero me suena todo a chino, donde podría encontrar mas información al respecto?

Comment: Para ellos creo que vas a necesitar JavaScript, ese CSS solo sirve para imágenes dentro del select (el cual no se pueden añadir, no de forma normal). Lo suyo sería que con JS detectaras que opción el usuario a seleccionado y mostrar lo que necesites (añadiendo clases, quitándolas...) Si no eres mucho de JavaScript, JQuery es mucho más amigable a la hora de escribir.

Comment: Pues mira, como precisamente me has pillado jugando con Javascript, te he elaborado el js que necesitas. Voy a añadirle unas anotaciones explicativas y enseguida te comparto el fiddle. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actualización porque no había entendido bien al OP**

Para poder hacer zoom en la imagen en función de la opción elegida, también necesitarás Javascript para poder relacionar los elementos entre sí. En este caso, lo que haremos será asignarle a la imagen la `class` equivalente al `value` seleccionado.

He elegido una forma muy burda de hacer zoom en cada elemento, seguro que puedes perfeccionarlo. Pero lo que necesitas para poder trastearlo por CSS, que es crear una relación entre los dos elementos, ya te lo da este Javascript. ;)

```js
let cocheSelec = document.getElementById('coche'); /* buscamos el select por ID */

function optionImg() {
  let opcionActiva = cocheSelec.value,
    /*extraemos el valor que esté seleccionado*/
    cocheImg = document.querySelector('#coche-img img'); /* buscamos la imagen en cuestión*/

  if (cocheImg.hasAttribute("class")) {
      cocheImg.removeAttribute("class"); /*quitamos la clase anterior*/
       }
      cocheImg.setAttribute("class", opcionActiva); /* le añadimos la class con el value activo*/

  }
  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', optionImg, false); /*ejecutamos la función al cargar el DOM*/
  cocheSelec.addEventListener('change', optionImg, false); /* y la volvemos a ejecutar cada vez que se cambie de opción*/
```

```css
#coche-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#coche-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 45% 75%;
}

#coche-img img.rueda,
#coche-img img.parrilla {
  transform: scale(3);
}

#coche-img img.rueda {
  top: -90px;
  left: -170px;
}

#coche-img img.parrilla {
  top: -0px;
  left: 400px;
}


/*añade las demás clases y modifica su posición para mostrar lo que quieras*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>PARTES DEL COCHE</h1>
  <form action="a.php">
    <select name="coche" id="coche">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="rueda">Rueda</option>
      <option value="parrilla">Parrilla</option>
      <option value="espejo">Espejo</option>
      <option value="puerta">Puerta</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <br>
  <div id="coche-img">
    <img src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/AebbV/s1/audi-a3-sportback-45-tfsi-e-2021.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Método para hacer zoom en diversas imágenes en función de la clase (no es lo que pregunta el OP)**

Como te comentaba, por la manera en que están anidados los elementos no se puede hacer con CSS puro, porque no se relacionan de manera directa en el DOM.

Para conseguir esa relación, se puede asignar a cada imagen una `class` igual al `value` de la opción con la que queremos relacionarla. Por ejemplo, añadir `class="rueda"` a la imagen que corresponda a la opción con `value="rueda"`.

Después, con un poco de Javascript añadimos `class="activa"` a la imagen cuya clase coincida con el `value` de la opción seleccionada. Y lo demás, ya sabes, con un poco de CSS, todo apañado.

De todas formas, tienes explicaciones detalladas en el fiddle, por si te da por aprender un poco de chino. ;)

```js
let cocheSelec = document.getElementById('coche'); /* buscamos el select por ID */

function optionImg() {
  let opcionActiva = cocheSelec.value, /*extraemos el value que esté seleccionado*/
    imgActiva = document.querySelector('img.'+opcionActiva), /* buscamos el img cuya clase se llame igual que la opción seleccionada*/
    restoImg = document.querySelectorAll('img:not(.'+opcionActiva+')');/* buscamos el resto de los img no seleccionados*/
    imgActiva.classList.add('activa'); /* a la imagen con la clase seleccionada le añadimos la clase "activa"*/
    
    restoImg.forEach(restImg => { 
      restImg.classList.remove('activa'); /*al resto de las imágenes les quitamos la clase "activa"*/
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', optionImg, false); /*ejecutamos la función al cargar el DOM*/
cocheSelec.addEventListener('change', optionImg, false); /* y la volvemos a ejecutar cada vez que se cambie de opción*/
```

```css
img {
  transition: transform 0.3s linear; /*una transición molonga nunca está de más :) */
}
img.activa {
  transform: scale(1.1); /*cuando la imagen esté activa, hacer más grande)*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    img {
        width: 40%
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h1>PARTES DEL COCHE</h1>
    <form action="a.php">
        <select name="coche" id="coche">
            <option value="rueda">Rueda</option>
            <option value="parrilla">Parrilla</option>
            <option value="espejo">Espejo</option>
            <option value="puerta">Puerta</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <br> 
    <img class="rueda" src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/AebbV/s1/audi-a3-sportback-45-tfsi-e-2021.jpg">
    <img class="parrilla" src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/AebbV/s1/audi-a3-sportback-45-tfsi-e-2021.jpg">
    <img class="espejo" src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/AebbV/s1/audi-a3-sportback-45-tfsi-e-2021.jpg">
    <img class="puerta" src="https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/AebbV/s1/audi-a3-sportback-45-tfsi-e-2021.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y la explicación, miraré de adaptar el código a lo que buscaba inicialmente!

Comment: Perdona, no había entendido bien lo que pedías. Despiste mío! He actualizado mi respuesta para incluirte el Javascript que necesitarás para hacer zoom en diversas partes de una imagen. Pero muy sutil en señalarlo, gracias por la cortesía. :P